# Rate of Change with respect Q

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$M = 2/3 * \log10(E/0.007)$

I need to calculate the rate of change of $M$ with respect to $E$ if $E = 60,000$ and previously $M = 7.7$

It's been a while since I did this and it's for a friend so forgive me if my workings are rusty/plain wrong

Multiply both sides by 1.5:
$1.5M = \log10(60,000/0.007)$
$1.5M = 6.933053210369459$
$   M = 6.933053210369459/1.5$
$   M = 4.62203547358$

If previous $M$ was $7.7$ then rate of change is
$7.7/4.62203547358 = 1.666$

Forgive me if I'm completely wrong

EDIT: OK I think I was way off mark. Attached is rough workings of how I proceeded. Grateful for any comments [image]